# Would a built-in TikZ/LaTex driver for Graphviz be useful?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex

Graphviz doesn't support TikZ/LaTeX.
Is **dot2tex** sufficient or would a TikZ/LaTeX driver help?